# how to create the script required for the systemd service

Tags: command-line, scripts

hey i'm trying to get my system to run a terminal command on startup everything i've found says to launch a script using a systemd service but nothing even begins to go into what i'd even type in that script and I'm not a programmer. the command i want to run is `rclone sync / b2-004:alice-ubtntu-2295 --copy-links`

I use Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What you need to do is to write a systemd Service Unit which executes the command. This is an extremely common task and there thousands of webpages explaining that. Just search for something like "create systemd Service unit".

Comment: Trust the documentation on the local system over what some Internet Rando says. Internet Rando has no knowledge of your exact circumstances. Build your knowledge. Read `man systemd systemd.service` Take advice from https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple means to get it done, but please look at `man systemd systemd.service` to learn a bit more:

1. **Create the systemd unit file with your nano text editor**:

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/my-clone-sync.service
   ```
2. **Add the following lines**:

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=Clone Sync Service

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/clone sync / b2-004:alice-ubtntu-2295 --copy-links
   RemainAfterExit=yes

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Make sure to provide the full path to the `clone` command if it's not in the system's default PATH.
3. **Save and exit**:

   Save the changes to the systemd unit file and exit the text editor.

   - `ctrl + X`
   - `shift + Y`
   - `Return key`
4. **Enable and start the service**:

   After modifying the unit file, enable and start the service as previously described:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl enable my-clone-sync.service
   sudo systemctl start my-clone-sync.service
   ```
5. **Check the service status**:

   To verify that the service is running and monitor its status:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl status my-clone-sync.service
   ```