# Ubuntu freezes and apps don't work after I moved a file to init.d

Tags: freeze, init.d

I used `sudo mv` to put an `.sh` file into `etc/init.d` to make the system go through it on startup, but I either read a bad guide or didn't read carefully because I didn't configure it as I would in point 2.3 here (https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-script-on-startup). After restarting the system Ubuntu treats me as if I was a new user (wants me to login into online accounts etc.) and shows the basic sidebar configuration (mine had different apps on it). No apps work even though they are visible, the system freezes each time I try to open an app.

I used `lsblk` and it listed some of the snaps I have, it also listed the partition on which Ubuntu is installed but the mountpoint was set to something like `dev/firefox` or alike (seemed strange to me, if it's important I will write the path in detail).

`fdisk -l` showed me all the partitions I have on my disk

`whoami` returns my correct username, logging out and in didn't help

`firefox` returns
`mkdir: cannot create directory 'home/user': Permission denied` , this result is printed a few more times with some alterations.

I checked my `home` folder and it seems empty (nothing is printed when I `ls`). Is it possible that I somehow removed this directory? I guess there's no fixing that and I should just reinstall?

Comment: Did you try removing that script?

Comment: If that does not work, reinstall. That's way easier than fixing an issue you don't know what is causing

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I removed the script through the terminal, the same problem occurs. If no one suggests something to check on, I will be forced to reinstall, yes.

Comment: hi @Zmyśliwiec I don't have answer but the cause and resolution to:  `No apps work... system freezes each time I try to open an app` would depend on the script you run. For the future, I would recommend to run any startup script/commands through `systemd service`. For how to create and enable systemd service, go through these posts please: `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd` | `https://askubuntu.com/a/1485275/928088` | `https://fabianlee.org/2022/01/04/ubuntu-running-a-bash-script-periodically-with-a-system-level-systemd-timer/`. Thanks.

Comment: @Zmyśliwiec Are you able to open terminal? If yes, try to open `firefox` (or any app) through terminal. Then modify/edit your post with error or any message you get in the terminal. You can open a terminal by: `CTRL+ALT+T or Windows logo key+T`: `https://www.wikihow.com/Open-a-Terminal-Window-in-Ubuntu`. Thanks.

Comment: @Jags thank you for trying to help me out. I updated the post with information on the ```firefox``` result and some more... it seems I blasted my ```home``` into oblivion, no idea how.

Comment: @Zmyśliwiec From the output of running Firefox in terminal and `ls` shows nothing, I would say get your personal data out (if there's any in the system) to external drive either from running system or from Live USB. Then go for a clean installation. And as I've said previously, in future, run any startup scripts/commands through a `systemd service`. How-to links are in my previous comments. Thanks.